# Which is correct "Your file can be found at/in/on C:\Users\User\Desktop/file.txt"?

Tags: prepositions

I am writing a program that creates a file and lastly tells you where the file can be found.
Should I write:

"Your file can be found **at** C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.txt"
or **in** C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.txt?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Lambie, this question seems to be valid according to that page.

Comment: You can find that online. at a place versus in a place, as in this program bumph:http://www.jaburt.com/eq/eqsettings.htm

Comment: None of the above - *Your file **IS** C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.txt*. Alternatively, that file ***can be found  IN** C:\Users\User\Desktop* (files are ***in*** folders, not ***on*** or ***at*** them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be confused if you say the file is at a specific location:

> Your file is at C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.txt

But non-technical users might conceivably be confused by that. You could avoid that with an alternate construction like

> The complete path to your file is C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.txt

You would use *in* if you just want to give the directory:

> Your file, file.txt, is in C:\Users\User\Desktop\